# PHP preg_replace escaped plus sign not working

Tags: php, regex

this

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]+-]/", "", $val);
```

and plus sign escaped

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]\+-]/", "", $val);
```

Are removing plus signs from $val when I want to allow plus signs, how do I escape the plus sign properly?

Comment: I think the problem is around `[:space:][:blank:]`. What do you really want to match/replace?

Comment: Try it with `/[^a-z\d\s\+-]+/i`

Comment: @DanLee `+` doesn't need escaping in a character class. `-` does.

Comment: no that didn't work, same problem

Comment: Also, `\+` is useless, `\\+` __might__ work

Comment: No luck Ugo - Regex's are a pain!

Comment: Florent I want to only allow the characters in the square brackets, everything else is removed

Comment: @DaveRandom Not true, try it yourself. And user1209203 of course it works, I see it right in front of me. You are doing it *wrong*

Comment: @DanLee [Actually](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), except for `]`, `^`, `-`, and backslash, _"The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use `[+*]`."_ [Example here](http://regexr.com?31guc). In retrospect, I think you were arguing the `-`, not the `+`. In that case, you're right: those aforementioned characters _"can be included ... by placing them in a position where they do not take on their special meaning."_

Comment: @Wiseguy Yep, I actually meant the `-`. But good explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:][:blank:]+\-]/", "", ':::test+++---:::');
```

Comment: Tested here http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and seems to work well... What do you want to achieve exactly? Could you please edit your question and give an example?

Comment: sorry your right that works it was then going through urldecode().